# How can I summon an ender dragon so it won't break blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been wanting to summon an Ender Dragon in the Overworld. But I don't want it to destroy my map. And I'm not going to turn the entire map into end stone and obsidian.

I have been using the `/summon EnderDragon` command. It will summon the dragon, but it just destroys everything.

Comment: Do you need the Ender Dragon to be able to move?

Comment: yes. it won't really be there to fight. but it will be there to look like a cool thing. it would be amazing for a map.

Answer (score 4):

Summon a EnderDragon with no AI:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}
```

Mobs with no AI will not move and will not be animated.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need other mobs to be able to break stuff, then you can just do this before you summon the dragon:

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

But try using tab to autocomplete those words to make sure the capitalization is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Ender Dragon to not do anything, summon it with this command:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}
```

But, then it is not animated and is pretty much just a statue. If you want the ender dragon to fly around, hurt people, but not damage blocks, use this gamerule and then summon a regular enderdragon:

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

You may want to use tab to make sure capitalization and spelling is correct.